# How to show a popup message when table is updated by another process

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In my project,i need to show a pop up message automatically when record of my project table is changed or update by another process. For example when some one add new record, a pop up message should be shown for every one who sees the system,that a new record has been added.

Comment: Is everybody is getting the change or update? If so by ajax call then add the pop-up message in the success of ajax call.

Comment: Gaurav Kalyan,The point is that in my project multiple users can login to the system simultaneously, If one user update the record, i want that every one should be informed that record is updated, I want to show the message to all users.

Comment: You will need to use ajax polling - very simple solution. It will be checking the data each second and notify with alert if content changed : )

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use ajax polling - very simple solution. It will be checking the data each second and notify with alert if content changed : )

Send the last update time with ajax, and check if theres something new after this time to actual.

```
$.post( "test.php", { last_update: var_with_last_time })
.done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
    // here check if the server returned something like {"changed":"true"}
    if(value == true){
        alert( "Data CHANGED");
        //Here fire new update request to refresh content, or you could do this in the same ajax call
        // You must change some php : )
    });
```

Comment: actually this would be a server push message...just like facebook notification...

Comment: What? my code? If yes, thats the sense. Everyone uses polling : ) The other way is to use Web Sockets, but the are not compatible with all browsers

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to add an `alert()` popup when AJAX has updated the data in the HTML DOM.

```
$.ajax{
  url: someCode.php,
  success: function(){
    // update the table in the HTML DOM
    alert('Table has been updated!');
  }
}
```

You may also use [the jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) if you want a fancy popup.

Comment: Rahul Desai thanks for the response, but what if table is updated from another source???. for example another user update the table .

Comment: Then you use polling -> check my answer

Comment: @ArifHussaini Please post your relevant code snippet so that I can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

create a hidden div like this:

```
   <div class="popupwindow" style="display:hidden"> change has been made</div>
```

you can style this div to look like a lightbox or whatever you want

if you are using jquery ajax, in you success function

```
   $(".popupwindow").fadeIn(400);
```

you can also make it fade out after an amount of time
or you can use alert method instead of a hidden div, it is up to you